# mynamespace/packageA 1.0.x-dev requires mynamespace/package-virtual 1.0 -> no matching package found

Tags: php, composer-php

I have several packages.  One depends on a virtual package that 2 of the others provides.  For the simplicity sake I am only focusing on packageA (package that requires the virtual) and packageB (one of the packages that provides the virtual).

**PackageA**

```
{
    "require": {
        "mynamespace/package-virtual": "1.0"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "mynamespace/packageB": "PackageB provides package-virtual",
        "mynamespace/packageC": "PackageC also provides package-virtual and can be installed with or without PackageB being present"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

**PackageB**

```
{
    "provide": {
        "mynamespace/package-virtual": "1.0"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

This all worked fine while I was using dev-master as a requirement for both packges in my application that used both of these packages:

**MyAPP using dev-master**

```
{
    "require": {
        "mynamespace/packageA": "dev-master",
        "mynamespace/packageB": "dev-master"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

However, when I tagged 1.0.0-rc1 on each package and attempted to change my dev requirement to 1.0.x-dev composer started complaining that it could not find `mynamespace/package-virtual`

**MyAPP using 1.0.x-dev**

```
{
    "require": {
        "mynamespace/packageA": "1.0.x-dev",
        "mynamespace/packageB": "1.0.x-dev"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

**Running composer update**

```
# composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for mynamespace/packageA 1.0.x-dev -> satisfiable by mynamespace/packageA[1.0.x-dev].
    - mynamespace/packageA 1.0.x-dev requires mynamespace/package-virtual 1.0 -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

**Things I have already tried**

- Changing the requires line for mynamespace/package-virtual to ^1.0 in mynamespace/packageA
- Changing the requires line for mynamespace/package-virtual to 1.0.* in mynamespace/packageA
- Changing the provides line for mynamespace/package-virtual to 1.* in mynamespace/packageB

**Why am I using a virtual and not just requiring packageB**

Because packageB is only a possible implementation of the virtual package.  packageC or some other package could potentially be used instead.

**Why am I not using replaces instead of provides**

Because packageB and packageC could both implement the virtual package and co-exist.  MyAPP may choose to use packageB in some scenarios and packageC in others.  Compare all of this to logging packages.  psr/log provides the interfaces for logging, but you must install one or more logging implementations to actually use it for logging.  Many different loggers implement the necessary interfaces and could all be installed simultaneously allowing the application to provide the user a selection of logging services to use.

**Why am I providing psuedo code instead of the actual composer.json files**

Because the code I am working on is not currently publicly available.  At some point it may be, but it is not now

**If the code isn't publicly installable, how are you installing via composer?**

I am running [Toran Proxy](https://toranproxy.com/) locally

**Question**

What am I doing wrong?  Why did this all work fine under dev-master but start failing once I tagged an RC and moved to a version branch.

Answer (score 0):

So I am not sure if this is the actual answer, but if I run `composer install`instead of `composer update` after clearing the mynamspace directory from vendor, everything works fine.

I also did find that using Satis instead of Toran seemed to work fine with `composer update` as well.